# How we can grab value from list box and fills automatically related text box in new form

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a list box and its row source is "tblitems" with bellow fields.
Now I like when right click on this list box and select one option for example "new task" it opens new task form and automatically Grab the item number from a list box and fills  related text box "item number"  in "new task" form that is bounded to table "tbltask"

Now when I press "Apply" button it insert new record in "tbltask".
[image]

```
  tblItems
  item number (pk)
 item name (text)

 tbltask
  task number (auto number,pk)
  item number
  enter image description here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a value from a list box in a form is:

```
Me.List_Box_Name.Value
```

Or if you have unbound values then get it based on the column:

```
Me.List_Box_Name.Column(2)
```

or whichever column you need.

You can then populate fields with `DLookup` or a recordset.  Then if you want this to happen when you open a new form, you may want to look into this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Stuff you want to happen when that form loads
End Sub
```

**Updated**

The following will print out the value each time you click it.  You can use this method to trigger a new form to open, or you can have a user click a submit button afterwards.

```
Private Sub Test_List_Click()
    Debug.Print Me.Test_List.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_Name"
End Sub
```

Now I'm not exactly sure the best way to add your variable to the opened form.  If it were me with my limited knowledge, I would add a global or public string and have the `Form_Load()` check to see if that string length is greater than 0.  If yes then it will populate the field.

Hope that helps

**Update 2**

Actually this link will help you populate a field from previous form:

[MS Access - open a form taking a field value from a previous form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723468/ms-access-open-a-form-taking-a-field-value-from-a-previous-form)

Comment: thanks i want to use Me.List_Box_Name.Value for the unbound text box "txtItem" in new form  when form loads(txtItem=Me.List_Box_Name.Value) but i do not know how to write that by code.

Comment: So do you want the listbox to be populated when the form loads??  Or do you want to get the value from the list box after a user picks an item from the list box?

Comment: i want to get the value from the list box after a user picks an item from the list box and then use this value in the new form will be load.